# Rails 4 - how do I add an index route for a nested resource, in order to list all items independent of parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, nested-routes

I've got a nested resource `Bar` that belongs to `Foo`. I can successfully list all `Bar` objects that belong to any given `Foo`. But I also want to be able to generate a view with all `Bar` items listed together, from whatever `Foo` object they belong to.

The model structure is:

```
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord
  has_many :bars
end

# app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

The routing is defined as:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :foos do
  resources :bars
end
```

I get the expected routes from this configuration:

```
   foo_bars GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars(.:format)      bars#index
            POST   /foos/:foo_id/bars(.:format)      bars#create
new_foo_bar GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/new(.:format)  bars#new
   edit_bar GET    /bars/:id/edit(.:format)          bars#edit
        bar GET    /bars/:id(.:format)               bars#show
            PATCH  /bars/:id(.:format)               bars#update
            PUT    /bars/:id(.:format)               bars#update
            DELETE /bars/:id(.:format)               bars#destroy
       foos GET    /foos(.:format)                   foos#index
            POST   /foos(.:format)                   foos#create
    new_foo GET    /foos/new(.:format)               foos#new
   edit_foo GET    /foos/:id/edit(.:format)          foos#edit
        foo GET    /foos/:id(.:format)               foos#show
            PATCH  /foos/:id(.:format)               foos#update
            PUT    /foos/:id(.:format)               foos#update
            DELETE /foos/:id(.:format)               foos#destroy
```

What I need is to generate a route for `bars#index` that isn't scoped within the context of `foo`. In other words, I essentially want:

```
bars  GET    /bars(.:format)      bars#index
```

I've tried using the shallow option, thus:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :foos, shallow: true do
  resources :bars
end
```

However, this doesn't support the :index action, per the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html).

What's the best way to do this? There's a helpful Stack Overflow discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811163/rails-nested-resources-conflict-how-to-scope-the-index-action-depending-on-the), using a `before_filter` to determine scope -- but it's from 2009. Appreciate any specific guidance on how to set up both the controller and the `config/routes.rb` file appropriately!

Comment: Adding `resources :bars` separately doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep the scoped index method `foo_bars` and a separate `bars` route/view:

Create a custom route in `routes.rb`:

```
get 'bars' => 'bars#index', as: :bars
```

Set up your index method in your `bars` controller as described in your link or simply:

```
def index
  if params[:foo_id]
    @bars = Foo.find(params[:foo_id]).bars
  else
    @bars = Bar.all
  end
end
```

Then create a `bars` view directory (if you don't have one) and `index.html.erb`.

---

If you don't want to keep the scoped index method `foo_bars`:

Create a custom route in `routes.rb`:

```
get 'bars' => 'bars#index', as: :bars
```

Edit your existing routes to exclude the nested index:

```
resources :foos do
  resources :bars, except: :index
end
```

Then the `bars` controller could just be:

```
def index
  @bars = Bar.all
end
```

Then create a `bars` view directory (if you don't have one) and `index.html.erb`.